# Filter for JIRA issues with fixVersion containing "keyword"

Tags: jira

I'd like to search for all the JIRA tasks that have a fixVersion that begin with "keyword", so I'd like to match any issue with fixVersion values of "keyword-1", "keywords-forever", etc

Even matching all the fixVersions that *contain* "keyword" (such as "my-keyword-version") would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually gave up, but our IT staff did not, and they got this JQL fragment to work:

```
fixVersion in versionMatch("keyword.*")
```

This criteria will match any issue that has a fixVersion starting with "keyword".

A little rooting around seems to indicate this is part of the JQL Tricks Plugin.

Comment: Unfortunately this is no built in function in JIRA (as of Version 7.1.0) and you have to use this (non-free) [plugin](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/quickstart.html)

Comment: But versionMatch is documented on the Advanced Searching page for JQL right now

Answer (score 1):

According to [JRA-24152](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-24152) this is not possible yet (at least not using JQL).
However, you can use the workaround mentioned in the issue description:

Use the quicksearch-field and type in 'ff:keyword*' or whatever you want to filter for.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fixVersion ~ "keyword*"` to find all issues with a fixVersion starting with `keyword`

Answer (score 0):

The JQL has been slightly changed. The correct syntax would now be:

`fixVersion in versionMatches("keyword.*")`